# Is it possible that the DNA of an individual changes significantly over a period?

Tags: dna

Is it possible that the DNA of an individual changes significantly over a period ?

Comment: What do you mean by "significantly"?

Comment: Not that significant that changes your identity, but that significant that may change your life.